# How do I get my fourth monitor to work?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, crossfire

I'm currently running three monitors in a fully working configuration. I have one 2560x1440 and two 1920x1080

I'd like to add an additional 1920x1080 monitor. However, I haven't managed to make it receive any signal while the other three monitors are running.

My GPU configuration consists of two [Gigabyte 7970 GHz Edition](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125439) running in **CrossFire**. I'm extending the desktop **without Eyefinity** and I'm using **Windows 7 64-bit**.

**Things I have tried:**

- Running the new monitor **alone**. The monitor worked fine.
- Running the new monitor **alongside** two of the old monitors. The new monitor worked fine.
- Using **active** adapters for all three 1920x1080 monitors
- Using **passive** adapters for all three 1920x1080 monitors.
- Using **no** adapters.
- Connecting **one** 1920x1080 to my second GPU and the other monitors to my first GPU.
- Connecting **two** 1920x1080 to my second GPU and the other monitors to my first GPU.

I recognize the fact that I haven't tried using any adapters for the 2560x1440. The local price for an active Dual Link DVI adapter hovers around $90. Thus I'd like to get others' opinions on the matter before I go out and potentially waste said money.

**Note regarding duplication:** I'm aware that there are other, similar questions. However, I believe this question is warranted as I've yet to find another question related to my GPUs' model and my specific setup of resolutions.